# Take single column value in multiple column

Tags: sql, mysql

[I have a mysql database as shown as follows.
My Database has the following format table name (subwise_gpa)

```
StudentId   SubjectId   Lg  Gp
2001010         1200    A+  4
2001010         1201    A   3.75
2001010         1202    A-  3.50
2001010         1203    B   3.00
2001010         1204    B+  3.25
2001010         1205    C   2.25
2001010         1206    C+  2.50
```

and a table name subject_details as follows

```
subjectId   subjectCr   subjectTitle    subjectCode
1200               3    Title........   Code1
1201               3    Title........   Code2
1202               3    Title........   Code3
1203               3    Title........   Code4
1204               2    Title........   Code5
1205               3    Title........   Code6
1206              0.5   Title........   Code7
```

I want a basic logic behind  to print the result as follow from that table using php mysql.

Final result [described in the image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcyvR.jpg

Comment: @user2182349 A "requirements dump" is a reason to downvote the question, not a reason to close.  If the question is asking for a task to be completed which has multiple moving parts -- then the correct close vote would be Needs Focus.  If the details are reliant on text within screenshots, then vote to close as Unclear. The way to disincentivize abuses of volunteers in this community is to not post an answer and downvote the question.  A close vote should not be used as a "super downvote".

Comment: @Md.N Your "emergency" is completely irrelevant to any question asked on Stack Overflow.  Thousands of future readers of this page will derive no value from the fact that you have real world time constraints.  Please do not add irrelevant text to your question.  Please never post textual details as screenshots -- this format is useless to humans who use screenreader technology and the current state of web crawlers.  If you are a developer, please show your best attempt to solve your task using code block formatting.